# Linux 3.5: Safe to `read(2)` from same fd `open(2)` `/dev/urandom` from multiple threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, linux-device-driver

Is it safe to do this:

```
int fd;

void thread_main()
{
    char buf[M];
    ssize_t r = read(fd, buf, M);
    assert(r == M);
    ...
}

int main()
{
    fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
         start_thread(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
         join_thread(i);
}
```

That is: After `open(2)`ing `"/dev/urandom"` from the main thread, is it safe to `read(2)` from it unsynchronized from different thread contexts?

Under what circumstances will the assert fire?  Will two threads ever get the same data?  What could go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is safe insofar as it will not crash. The `assert` will never trigger. No two threads will (*should*) ever get the same random data (it is highly unlikely but still possible that two threads get two "different" random sequences which are *incidentially* the same, so this cannot be 100% guaranteed).

`/dev/urandom` will never block or return fewer bytes than you try to read, however, if you read a large enough amount, it will eventually run out of entropy, so the quality of the random numbers will eventually degrade slightly. Usually, this is still just good enough, and it takes a whole while before that happens too, but it's something to be aware of (most people don't need to care, but it might *not* be acceptable, depending on what you do).

`read`/`write` are threadsafe (insofar as they won't crash or corrupt data or leave descriptors in undefined states) and in this special case also *should not* intermingle/split up bytes between reads/writes to/from different processes. In general, however, `read`/`write` **do not guarantee this**. They *may* intermingle data on concurrent reads/writes, on some devices.

It should however not be a problem, since random bits are still random if you get some other random bits and someone else gets some (different) bits in between.
If you think it is a problem for you, use `readv` which **guarantees** strict atomicity (no mixing/intermingling, ever). Anything that goes in/out of `readv`/`writev` is processed as one atomic unit, always (*except* on pipes, when exceeding a size of `PIPE_BUF`, as pointed out by rodrigo).

Comment: No exceptions? From `man readv`: "The data transfers [...] are atomic [...] but see pipe(7) for an exeption."

Comment: Ah yes, pipes transfer sizes, you're right on that one, my bad :-)

Comment: "_No two threads will (should) ever get the same random data_" IOW, the *statistical correlation between these data is null*: they should be equal at the same frequency as true random numbers are equal.

Comment: In some sense, but not quite. There is a finite entropy pool ("real random" data) which is "amplified" by going through bit hashing. If you only read a moderate amount of values, the entropy pool will not be depleted (as new entropy is generated over time) so you basically have "real" random data, but for a correlation analysis you would need an considerable amount of values which would certainly deplete the pool, leaving you with a somewhat non-deterministic (since there's real random bits in it) but still _pseudo_-random sequence. Insofar, such a correlation analysis probably won't fly.

Comment: Also, something like "the same frequency as true random numbers are equal" is a moot thing. True random numbers do not necessarily follow an uniform distribution, and even if they do, they do not necessarily look "random" at all. You would be surprised how "totally not random" true random values can look sometimes. Insofar, coparing frequencies does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

read is thread safe in the sense that it is a system call, and if you do multiple reads from multiple threads, each read will be processed serially. That is to say thread A will read M bytes, thread B will read the next M bytes, and so on, rather than thread A reading a few bytes, thread B reading a few bytes, then thread A reading more bytes.

The same is true of write.

The usual issue with multiple threads doing reads and writes is that often they read/write 1 character at a time, so there's a hack of a lot of opportunity to mix up where the input goes and the output comes from - and often the confusion is added to by language runtime libraries existing on top of read/write